# Is there a way to specify an table/index is sorted by more than one column?

Tags: sql-server, index, timestamp

Suppose I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Timestamp] DATETIME2(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT (SYSUTCDATETIME()),
    [Data] INT NOT NULL
);
```

And suppose I need to look up rows by `ID` (e.g. for joins) and by `Timestamp` (e.g. for date-range search).

The usual way to do this would be to add an index on `Timestamp`, but this seems like a massive waste of resources (almost a complete copy of the table) when `Timestamp` should be in order in the table in the first place. So two questions:

1. Is there a way to enforce `Timestamp` being strictly ascending along with `Id`? (i.e. to make sure pathological cases like changing the server's system clock, leap seconds, `Id`'s Identity-ness being overruled).
2. Is there a way for SQL Server to make use of the above enforcement and treat the table as indexed on both `Id` and `Timestamp`?

I suspect the answer to (1) may be yes, but that (2) is probably a no, rendering (1) a bit useless, but I'm happy to be proven wrong.

*Any version of SQL Server acceptable*

Comment: I think that `Id` and `Timestamp` will increase together. Do you really need a timestamp?

Comment: I do if there needs to be facility for search for all rows from e.g. the last week.

Comment: You shouldn't consider an index a sort. A sort is a sort. Your queries only come out in index order as happy accident, on a system with a temp table file split for example this wouldn't occur.

Comment: You can make your timestamp to be a clustered key. For pointing search by id you can add non-clustered index on id, but your range searches will use clustered index in the key order

Comment: Yes, consider a cluster on timestamp and NCI on id. Just beware if you create a clustered index on timestamp column, and it's not unique, SQL Server will ad another unuquifier hidden column to the table. But it may be worth it anyway.

Comment: @Paul: I'm not planning on using the table ordering in place of an ORDER BY; indexes are sorted for fast lookup, which is all I'm after.

Comment: @sepupic: I don't see an improvement from ID clustered, Timestamp NCI to vice versa (not without information about which kind of lookup will happen more often anyway) - am I missing something? [Edit: clustering on Timestamp lets me get directly at the many relevant rows without going via the index to get them all. This argument doesn't apply to ID as it'll be a single row lookup. Sound about right?]

Comment: @dean: If the timestamp was unique, I wouldn't need the ID column at all :)

Comment: >>> I don't see an improvement from ID clustered, Timestamp NCI to vice versa<<< Now you cannot do your range scans of timestamp in a clustered index, and you said this field is used for range seeks. If you have NCI on timestamp and it will be used, lookups in clustered will be done, and this comes at a cost. Your id is used only for joins,you said, so the clustered on timestamp still will be used. And **only if** you use pointing search on ID, NCI on id will be used. You even did not say you do these searches, so maybe you don't and clustered on timestamp will be enough

Answer (score 1):

You can create a clustered index on both id and timestamp columns and even define different sorting order for each column if you want to: 
`create unique clustered index idx on TestTable(id asc, [timestamp] asc)`
But it won't make much sense in this case for these reasons:

1. The engine does not know that timestamp increases along with id, so if you run a query with condition on timestamp, it'll still perform a full scan.
2. All additional columns that are included in clustered index will also be included in all non-clustered indexes.
3. An older timestamp still could be inserted into the table with newest id.

So you are gaining nothing and only wasting space when you create a new index and slowing down inserts as timestamp order still will have to be maintained.

Creating an index only on timestamp column seems like a waste of resources (2 out of three columns of entire table will be included in an index), but actually it's very common for size of all indexes be greater than the size of the table. Slow queries are also wasting a lot of resources, so just create it if it'll boost select queries and if slower inserts will not be a problem.

To finally answer your question: as you can't implement this logic using indexes and constraints, the only way I see is to create an [INSTEAD OF INSERT Trigger](https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms175089(v=sql.105).aspx). It'll hurt insert performance, but prior to insert you can check if older timestamp already exists in the table and then modify the timestamp, not insert the data, raise an error - up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply two diffrent sort orders (by diffrent column) using only one index. An index is a structure which store a data on a disk in logical order (B-tree approach) based on columns from index declaration.

It is worth pointing out, that a storage isn't usually problem nowdays and you should focus on CPU, network and engine (IO operations) efforts. And even in this case, you didn't say that, you just said that it would be waste of resources, but it isn't. In many cases, use of additional space for indexes gives your CPU, network and SQL Engine relief when quering data. Sometimes it is good solution for deal with concurrency or deadlock issues too.

In your case, if you want to ensure ability to identify unique row, you have to create `Id` column. You shouldn't rely on `Timestamp` in this matter.

Let's consider following approaches.

### Solution 1

- Create clustered index on `Timestamp` column.
- Create Primary Key as unique nonclustered index only on `Id` column (`Timestamp` will be included as clustered index key).

You said about range scans with `Timestamp` column, so better to have `Data` content in the same index (range means lot of data which should be availabe without lookup). This requires for example clustered index on `Timestamp` column (which is WHERE predicate). This will be most efficient approach to query data this way.

For other queries which use `Id` column, engine will use second nonclustered index. But if `Data` column is required, it will cause `Key Lookup` (additional effort for CPU, engine, IO).

It's quite good resolution if your queries mainly use `Timestamp` as WHERE predicate and require `Data` column. Still there is some effort when querying by `Id` column.

In terms of storage, one row have 16 bytes for clustered index and 12 bytes for nonclustered index (28 bytes), so let's think about something similar.

### Solution 2

- Create Primary Key as unique clustered index only on `Id` column. Most narrow option.
- Create nonclustered index on `Timestamp` column and include `Data` column (`Id` will be included as clustered index key).

Best way in terms of query performance would be to create two covering indexes. In this approach there will be no need to lookup when quering data by `Id` or `Timestamp` column, just smooth read from appropriate index (seek or scan).

Compared to Solution 1 there is additional space used (4 bytes), but we gain benefits when query data (no key lookups).

### Remarks

Always create clustered index firstly, creating it as last one enforce rebouild all nonclustered indexes (replace RID with Clustered Key).

It's also worth noting, that it will be some impact on insert/update/delete operations in both solutions presented above. But it would be acceptable looking at the structure and row size, and still benefits should compensate it.

And one more thing.

It looks like you want implement time series database in SQL Server.

There are complex solution to achive this like [Azure Time Series Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/time-series-insights/), [InfluxDB database](https://www.influxdata.com/) or others similar database engine. If you want to stick with SQL Server, you can look for articels about it.

- [Time series databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series_database)
- [Time-series data: Why (and how) to use a relational database instead
  of NoSQL](https://blog.timescale.com/time-series-data-why-and-how-to-use-a-relational-database-instead-of-nosql-d0cd6975e87c)
- [Top 10 Time Series Databases](https://blog.outlyer.com/top10-open-source-time-series-databases)